# problem with a join

Tags: c#, linq, join

I have this code:

```
int se = (int) settings.GruppoSegreteria;
    var acc = db.USR_Accounts.Where( p => p.ID_Gruppo == se);
    var segreterie = from s in db.USR_Utenti 
                     join h in acc on s.ID equals h.USR_UtentiReference
                     select s;
```

And this error:

```
The type of one of the expressions in the join clause is incorrect.  Type inference failed in the call to 'Join'
```

I don't understand it.
Can you help me?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are joining on `s.ID` and `h.USR_UtentiReference`. I guess they are not of the same type? You have to join on two ints (for example). You can't join on a int and some other type.